# You set a table before me in the presence of my adversaries; You anointed my head with oil; my cup overflows.?

Tags: tehilim-psalms

Tehillim - Psalms - Chapter 23

5 .You set a table before me in the presence of my adversaries; You anointed my head with oil; my cup overflows.

Could someone explain The meaning of this verse?

I will controle my adversaries?
I'm above them?
They have no power over me?

How are we to understand this verse?

Answer (score 5):

The commentaries (Radak, Metzudos, Malbim) on the verse say the setting of the table before David is an honor for him. Possibly an allusion to his becoming king.

This honor being done for him in the presence of his enemies is both a special joy for David and a public proof that they have no ability to oppose his being honored.

The oil anointed upon his head is an allusion to his becoming king. And the cup overflowing is his recognition that he will continue to enjoy this satisfaction.

Comment: Interesting.But is this for only King David or for the whole house of Isreal?

Comment: Seems personal. Many of the psalms are written by individuals to give thanks for their personal help they received from God. David especially focuses on his personal situations in many of his psalms.