# Are the Psalms for us?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, literature

The Psalms of David all seem to be about his joy or his sadness, crying out to Hashem.

But to make it clear, are these Psalms for us as well: when we sing them do we also pray them? Or are we talking about the greatness of David and his faith? Maybe both? Maybe some Psalms are for us and others are for David?

What can we learn from them if we can’t use them in prayer?

Comment: Good question. The psalms are mainly prayers of David, who was praying for his specific needs, what are we making when we read psalmes

Comment: Some areas to clarify: 1) "Psalms of David" -  Do you mean all the Psalms or just the ones that start with words "A Psalm to David" or "To David, a Psalm"? 2) Last question - who says we can't use them in prayer? As a matter of fact, the majority of our morning prayers includes entire Psalms or verses from various Psalms. Please clarify / edit.

Comment: @DanF Not saying anything,just trying to make things clear.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76268/you-set-a-table-before-me-in-the-presence-of-my-adversaries-you-anointed-my-hea

Comment: I do mean all the psalms,And I do think there for prayer today,just want to make it clear.

Comment: The book of Psalms is a collections of many different psalms and very diverse, some are hymns of praise, some are of gratitude to Hashem, some are forms of prayer, and some are about repentance and forgiveness, some are messianic and some are asking for revenge on Israel's enemies, some are even about a specific anonymous king and his wealth and splendor, or about a royal marriage involving a Tyrian princess (see psalm 45 for example). But even so, 70 percent of the book of Psalms is suitable for prayer and liturgy even today! That's why it is still so popular even 2500 years later!

Answer (score 3):

King David's words are timeless, and relevant in every single generation.

This teaching is spelled out in the Midrash (Shochar Tov, Tehillim 18:1):

> ר' יודן אומר בשם ר' יהודה אמר, כל מה שאמר דוד בספרו, כנגדו, וכנגד כל
> ישראל, וכנגד כל העיתים אמרו.
>
> R. Yodan said in the name of R. Yehuda, who said: “Everything that
> David said in his book, corresponded to himself, and corresponded
> against **all of Israel**; and he said it corresponding to **all of times**”.

In times of joy and otherwise, we should look to find ourselves and whatever situation we may be in, in the inspirational words of King David's Psalms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ; as it is lengthy explained in sefer [l'kutai mohoron 2, torah 125](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01572.html?dyn#HtmpReportNum0123_L2).

This is the actual quotation of Rabbi Nachman:

> קכה - מענין אמירת תהלים
>
> **מענין אמירת תהלים דבר עם אחד ואמר לו, שעקר אמירת תהלים לומר כל מזמורי תהלים על עצמו, למצא את עצמו בתוך כל מזמור ומזמור. ושאל אותו זכרונו לברכה: איך, ופרש לו רבנו, זכרונו לברכה, קצת, כי כל המלחמות שבקש דוד המלך, עליו השלום, שיצילהו השם יתברך מהם - הכל צריכין לפרש לעצמו על מלחמת היצר הרע וחילותיו, וכיוצא בזה בשאר המזמורים** (וכמבאר מזה לעיל בסימן קא). ושאל אותו: איך יפרש לעצמו מהפסוקים, שדוד המלך, עליו השלום, משבח את עצמו, כגון: "שמרה נפשי כי חסיד אני" (תהלים פ"ו), וכיוצא בזה. השיב לו: גם זה צריכין לפרש על עצמו, כי צריכין לדון את עצמו לכף זכות, ולמצא בעצמו איזה זכות ונקדה טובה, אשר בבחינת הנקדה טובה הזאת הוא בחינת חסיד, וכיוצא. ואמר לו רבנו, זכרונו לברכה: הלא אצל יהושפט כתיב (דברי הימים ב יז): "ויגבה לבו בדרכי ה'", שבדרכי ה' ועבודתו יתברך הגביה לבו קצת. עוד אמר לו רבנו, זכרונו לברכה: הלא בבקר אנו אומרים בתחלה: 'מה אנו מה חיינו' וכו', ואנו מקטינים עצמנו מאד, ואחר כך אנו אומרים: 'אבל אנחנו עמך בני בריתך' וכו', שאחר כך אנו מחזקים עצמנו ומרימים את עצמנו, ואנו מספרים את גדלתנו ומתפארים, שאנחנו עמו בני בריתו זרע אברהם יצחק ויעקב וכו', כי כך צריכין להתנהג בעבודת השם כנ"ל. ועין מזה ספר הראשון בסימן רפ"ב, על פסוק: "אזמרה לאלקי בעודי":
>
> Regarding the recitation of *T'hilim* he spoke to someone and said to him that the point of the recitation of *T'hilim* is to say all *mizmorei T'hilim* about himself - to find himself in every *mizmor*.
>
> And he of blessed memory asked him, "how?".
>
> So our Rabbi of blessed memory explained to him, in part, that all of the battles that King David *alav hashalom* asked Hashem to save him from - each [person] needs to explain it for himself regarding his evil inclination and its armies(?). Similar [comparisons apply] to the rest of the *mizmorim*. . .

The point is that for example when king david sais ''ki chasid ani'' acctually every person can find himself being a 'chasid' in certain areas. And so on.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I recommend http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76

Comment: Please edit in what he says, a summary of it would be very useful as well.

Comment: sorry, but I was searching for an English translation, but there wasn't to find, I can put the Hebrew version, would this work?

Comment: Thanks for this text of Rav Nachman Mibreslev, very strong. I feel that you can put the hebrew version, and translate it or summarize what you understand.

Answer (score 1):

the Psalms were composed with ruach hakodesh/prophecy which means he was a sort of spokesman for the word of God as David himself said:

> The Spirit of the LORD spoke through me; His word was on my tongue.
>   (Shmuel II 23:2)

some of the psalms were even intended for our times as can be seen [here](http://dafyomireview.com/269).

Also, David was the King of Israel which means he was the heart of the nation (this is why there are special mitzvot for the king to guard his heart from going astray) and being the first and foremost king this extended to all generations. Hence, the Psalms are for every jew for all times. Hence, even when he seems to be speaking only about himself, it applies for all jews at all times. (cant remember the source of this)